# C++ - Insert data into map of map loop

Tags: c++, maps

During a map of map loop what is the correct way to insert data?

In first moment in my code inside one function i insert some data to my map of map like this (and its work good):

```
outMap[TYPE_REQ_USER][req->number] = req;
```

After this my map size is 1.

In second moment, inside other function, i need to iterate the map and if i found the key `TYPE_REQ_USER` i need to add a new data to the map of map. I try like this but after this i print the map size and we said its 1 and not 2 (the expected)

My map of map loop to insert data:

```
 for (outMap_t::iterator itOutMap = outMap.begin(); itOutMap != outMap.end(); ++ itOutMap)
 {
      for (intMap_t::iterator itInMap = itOutMap->second.begin(); itInMap != itOutMap->second.end(); ++itInMap)
      {
        if (itOutMap->first == TYPE_REQ_USER)
        {
          //map insert
          outMap[TYPE_REQ_USER][req->number] = req;
        }
      }
 }
```

So what is wrong in my loop insert?

EDIT 2

So now for the same key (TYPE_REQ_USER) i can have two different elements.

So know when i'm trying to iterate the map and delete the elements for the key i'm having the segmentation fault error, because in first iteration i do:

qnRunningType_JobId.erase(itOutMap);

But in second iteration i have the sementation fault error because i'm trying to delete the `itOutMap` but we already deleted in first iteration..

Comment: Do you pass your map of maps to the function by reference? You may be copying it so not making persistent changes within your function.
Also, are you overwriting the value by mistake, rather than adding a new value?

Comment: Nop, because the map of maps belong to the class where i have the function. So its only call the map of map

Comment: Post some more code - the relevant bits of the two functions and the class they're members of.

Comment: I define the maps in my class.h, so in class.cpp its only to call the map of maps inside the function i need.

Comment: Well there doesn't seem to be anything wrong in this code, so without posting more code we won't be able to find what *is* wrong.

Comment: I already found my problem.. its because i cannot have two elements in same map with same key, in this case... TYPE_REQ_USER... if i put other key and try again the map have the size 2...

Comment: Yes, sorry i dont see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(comment converted to answer for completeness)

Using a `std::map`, inserting an item that already exists will **overwrite** the existing item. You can check if you've overwritten an item by using `std::map::insert` and checking the second item of the returned pair, as described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/insert/).

Comment: Thanks. I already solve this problem, when i inserting in loop iterating i do:

outMap[it->first][req->number] = req;

the it->first is equal to TYPE_REQ_USER so for the same TYPE_REQ_USER i have two different elements.

Please see my edit 2, to see my new problem